# Is it possible to run a Xamarin.UITests for Android to run on MAC with Visual Studio for MAC?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

With the release of Visual Studio for Mac, is it possible to run Xamarin.UITests for Android on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you could always do it before using Xamarin Studio, but it works in Visual Studio for Mac as well